# Set Workbook Variable from Userform Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am creating a macro for my co-workers.  They get a file daily and at the end of the day have to copy certain information to another workbook.  The macro is to take care of the copying.  I want to have a userform with a combobox popup that contains a list of current open workbooks so it knows which file to copy from.  How do I set it up so that the selection made there sets a workbook variable with that selection?

What I'm trying to do is:

```
Sub CopySub()

Dim wb As Workbook

UserForm1.Show

Set wb = Workbooks(ComboBox1.Value)
....Rest of Copy and Paste Code
```

Below is the code for the userform:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
'Take user selection and continue copy and paste code
UserForm1.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click()
'Cancel everything, end all code
End
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

  'Populate list box with names of open workbooks.

  Dim wb As Workbook

  For Each wb In Workbooks

    ComboBox1.AddItem wb.Name

  Next wb

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working now because `CopySub` doesn't know what\where `ComboBox1` is. Also, if the user clicks the form's X to close it instead of pressing the cancel button or clicks the OK button without selecting a workbook, `CopySub` will keep running.

There are a couple different ways to get the form information. The simplest with your current code is to properly reference `ComboBox1` and add a simple test.

```
Sub CopySub()
   Dim wb As Workbook

   UserForm1.Show
   If UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
      Exit Sub
   End If

   Set wb = Workbooks(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value)
   ' rest of code goes here

End Sub
```

Something else to think about though is ways to make your macro quicker and easier to run. If the only thing on your form is a Combobox for selecting the workbook and users will be starting the macro from a keyboard-shortcut or from the menu, consider having the macro ask if they want to run the macro on the active workbook. Clicking Yes to a question is a lot faster than having to click a dropdown box, select the workbook, and then click OK.

```
Sub CopySub()
   Dim wb As Workbook

   If MsgBox("Do you want to run the macro on '" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
      Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   Else
      UserForm1.Show
      If UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
         Exit Sub
      End If
      Set wb = Workbooks(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value)
   End If

   ' rest of code goes here

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I actually figured it out the problem which is what you said, I needed a global variable.  My fix will be below.  I had to create this step to ask for the workbook because the workbook the macro is to be run from will be the activeworkbook but I needed a way for the user to select the workbook to copy from.

Comment: I'll post my answer after 8 hours passes :)

Comment: @riotburn, I was guessing that might be the case but just in case it wasn't, I thought I'd go ahead and mention it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

After further searching I found the answer, and its the same as what mischab points out, I didn't create a global variable so there was no way for my userform to communicate with the subroutine.  I solved this by declaring a variable with scope for the whole workbook as such:

```
Public wb1 As String

Sub CopySub()

Dim wbCAR As Workbook

UserForm1.Show

Set wbCAR = Workbooks(wb1)
....Rest of code
```

and by setting the userform code to such:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
wb1 = ComboBox1.Value
UserForm1.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click()
Unload Me
End
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

  'Populate list box with names of open workbooks.
  Dim wb As Workbook
  For Each wb In Workbooks
    ComboBox1.AddItem wb.Name
  Next wb

End Sub
```